# Is license required to sell songs replayed on a virtual instrument?

Tags: copyright, music

Would it infringe copyright to replay the Star Wars theme on a virtual accordion app and sell the song as a lesson to play?

If not would it be allowed if its free?

I couldn't find anything on the internet in regards to replay copyrighted material on a virtual instrument/app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you could do that without infringing copyright. The Star Wars theme is a copyrighted piece of music, and creating a transcription of it would be considered a derivative work. Only the copyright holder can authorize such derivative works. Cost doesn't factor into it at all.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work

Comment: Those virtual instruments that *do* have it in their library paid some royalty to have that song available on the device.